# ASP.NET get sobre red del mismo segmento

Tags: php, c#, asp.net

tengo dos computadoras conectadas al mismo segmento de red, en una tengo ASP.NET corriendo y lo quiero es hacer un get desde otra maquina en el mismo segmento de red. Ya lo intente con un php y no tuve problemas, solo le pase la direccion ip y la ruta de mi método, cuando pretendo hacer lo mismo con una ruta de mi `ASP.NET` me tira un error 400. La ruta que me da ASP cuando ejecuto mi proyecto es

> https://localhost:55751

la ip de la maquina donde lo corro es : `192.168.100.10`
y le tiro un get como :

> http://192.168.100.10:55751/mirutaquedevuelveunjson

a lo cual me tira un `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.`

con php hago igual, solo cambio el puerto por el de `Xampp` y me queda algo como

> http://192.168.100.10:8080/mirutaquedevuelveunjsondephpenxampp

y este si me da un status 200
 , estoy usando `Postman` para enivar mis peticiones. Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación para hacer deployment?

Comment: Cuando ejecutas tu proyecto ASP me inmagino que utilizas el IIS Express. Es mejor instalar el IIS de forma local y configurar el proyecto ASP que utilize el IIS Local. Por defecto el IIS utiliza el puerto 80. Luego creas una nueva regla de entrada en el firewall para el puerto 80. Nota: por seguridad cuando no estes haciendo pruebas debes de desactivar la regla creada en el firewall. Pasate por este post: [How to configure IIS to access website](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html)